# Kubernetes Update Pods in Replication Controller behind Service

Tags: replication, service, kubernetes

We have a deployed API in Kubernetes. The API is deployed via replication controller to pods and a managing rc. I would like to update the configuration to the API pods using rolling-update. I can do that, however the only way I can get the rolling-update command to not error is by changing the name of the RC. But doing this breaks the link from my Service (exposed as a load balancer) to the RC and it cannot find my pods anymore. Does someone have an example config for updating a replication controller without changing the name?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
    name: my-api
    labels:
        name: my-api
spec:
    replicas: 4
    selector:
        name: my-api
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                name: my-api
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: my-api
                image: docker-registry.example.com/mynamespace/my-api
                command: [ "sh", "-c", "/do/the/thing/run"]
                resources:
                    limits:
                        cpu: 0
                ports:
                  - name: web
                    containerPort: 80
                env:
                  - name: "HELLO"
                    value: "WORLD"
```

And I would like, for example to change the env var "HELLO" to "Bob" or something.

Comment: Does someone have an `example config` for updating a replication controller without changing the name? Could you add the config you are using to try to make it work, i.e. could you add your attempts to solve the issue?

Comment: You shouldn't change the name of the RC. All you really need to change is the version and the docker container and issue the rolling update command

Comment: @Mike - I'm trying to just update config so no container version change is necessary

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a strategy that might work. Most of the documentation I was working off of had the Service selector based on the name of the pod. That doesn't work, because the name HAS to change when performing a rolling update. It's best to make the service.spec.selector something like "type=api-server" or some other metadata label then add type=api-server to your pods. (Remember services point at pods directly, not RCs)

Replication Controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
    name: my-api-{{randomDigits}}
    labels:
        name: my-api-{{randomDigits}}
spec:
    replicas: 4
    selector:
        name: my-api-{{randomDigits}}
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                name: my-api-{{randomDigits}}
                type: api-server
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: my-api
                image: docker-registry.example.com/mynamespace/my-api
                command: [ "sh", "-c", "/do/the/thing/run"]
                resources:
                    limits:
                        cpu: 0
                ports:
                  - name: web
                    containerPort: 80
                env:
                  - name: "HELLO"
                    value: "WORLD"
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: my-api-service
    labels:
        name: my-api-service
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
      - port: 80
    selector:
        type: api-server
```

Then if you want to update your pod's config, you just change {{randomDigits}} to something new and you can perform a rolling update without breaking the link from your Service to your Pods.